# fluent nHibernate Restrictions.Not seems not be working properly

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the association:

```
TableA 1 --- * TableB
```

I try to build a query, which returns me the list of the `TableA` items, whose ALL items (`TableB`) have a value in the column `X` and `Y`. But that query seems to be ignoring that `not null condition in the X and Y column`, why ?

Or, how to rebuild that query, maybe play with the subquery ?

```
TableA tabA = null;
TableB tabB = null;

var s = Session.QueryOver<TableA>(() => tabA)
                       .JoinAlias(() => tabB.TableBItems, () => tabB, JoinType.InnerJoin)
                       .Where(Restrictions.Conjunction()
                                          .Add(() => tabA.SomeID == 123)
                                          .Add(() => tabA.SomeNullableDate != null)
                             )
                       .Where(Restrictions.Not(
                                Restrictions.Conjunction()
                                            .Add(() => tabB.X == null)
                                            .Add(() => tabB.Y == null)
                             ))
                       .List<TableA>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a subquery to filter out TableA elements having null values in tabB-Items

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<TableA>()
    .JoinQueryOver(tabA => tabA.TableBItems)
        .Where(tabB => tabB.X == null || tabB.Y == null)
    .Select(Projections.Id());

var s = Session.QueryOver<TableA>()
    .Where(tabA => tabA.SomeID == 123 && tabA.SomeNullableDate != null)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(Projections.Id()).NotIn(subquery)
    .JoinQueryOver(tabA => tabA.TableBItems)
        .Where(tabB => tabB.X != null && tabB.Y != null)
    .List<TableA>();
```